# How to make EntityFramework Relation IQueryable?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

Let's assume i have these classes:

```
public class Car
{
  public int CarId { get; set} 
  public virtual ICollection<Door> Doors { get; set} 
}

public class Door
{
   public int DoorId { get; set} 
   public decimal Weight { get; set} 
   public int CarId { get; set} 
}
```

And i want to do something like this

```
foreach ( var car in db.Cars )
{
   var x = car.Doors.Min(d => d.Weight);
}
```

As i see in EFTraceLog he makes something like 
Select * from Doors where CarId = @...
and calculates "Min" on application server, not on db server

I have very big cars and doors tables, so this operation lasts for minutes. 
But if i change code to this

```
foreach ( var car in db.Cars )
{
   var x = db.Doors.Where(d => d.CarId == car.CarId).Min(d => d.Weight);
}
```

then it's few seconds.

Why there is such a big difference and how to fix it? 
The problem here is that it is much more simplier to write

```
var x = car.Doors.Min(d => d.Weight);
```

then

```
var x = db.Doors.Where(d => d.CarId == car.CarId).Min(d => d.Weight);
```

**Update**

We are using Entity Framework 5.0

**Update 2**

I have tried these variants, they are slow

```
var x = car.Doors.Select(door => door.Weight).Min();
var x = car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).Select(x => x.Weight).FirstOrDefault();
var x = car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).Select(x => x.Weight).First();
var x = car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).FirstOrDefault().Weight;
var x = car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).First().Weight;
```

Only this one is fast

```
var x = db.Doors.Where(d => d.CarId == car.CarId).Min(d => d.Weight);
```

**Update 3**

Best query produces this sql

```
declare @p__linq__0 Int32 = cast(N'204' as Int32);

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
MIN([Extent1].[Weight]) AS [A1]
FROM [dbo].[Doors] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CarId] = @p__linq__0
) AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: What SQL does the `Where` (your last line) statement generates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Linq to Entities` only support `Min` without the extra projection. That means your current `Min` will be invoked using Linq To Objects (causing your `Doors` collection to materialize - hence the produced SQL you see in your logs).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx):

**Supported:**

```
TSource Min<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
```

**Not Supported:**

```
TResult Min<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
```

You can try to use `OrderBy`, `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` (that **are** supported) to achieve the same result:

```
var min = car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).Select(x => x.Weight).FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPDATE:**

Apparently `Entity Framework` does not support Lazy-Load with Projection, it means that whenever you're loading referenced entities (`Car.Doors` in your case) the framework Lazy-Load all of it's data and you cannot choose which property (`Weight` in your case) to load.

That's the reason for the difference between the 2 calls:

```
// Accessing 'Doors' thru 'Car' means 'Lazy Load'
car.Doors.Select(x => x.Weight).Min();
```

But,

```
// No 'Lazy Load' involved, hence projection is possible
db.Doors.Where(x => x.CarId == carId).Select(x => x.Weight).Min();
```

You can also try to access `Car.Doors` and **Eager Load** `Doors`:

```
foreach ( var car in db.Cars.Include(x => x.Doors))
{
   var x = car.Doors.Select(x => x.Weight).Min();
}
```

(I used the shortened alternative for `Min` as proposed by **Servy**)

Comment: I had no way to validate, so I've deleted.

Comment: I tried car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).Select(x => x.Weight).First(); And car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).First().Weight. Both doesn't help. Still same query: Select * from Doors where CarId = @...

Comment: @YegorRazumovsky That's a different query than was suggested to you.  EF doesn't support `First`, only `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Tried car.Doors.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).Select(x => x.Weight).FirstOrDefault(); Same story

Comment: I revised my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per [haim770's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163046/1159478), the overload of `Min` that takes a projection isn't supported by EF, but you can just perform the projection first using `Select` instead to get the desired result:

```
var minWeight = db.Doors.Select(door => door.Weight).Min();
```

Comment: @YegorRazumovsky Sounds like your query provider isn't configured properly.  Do *any* queries get properly translated?  Do other queries on that particular table get translated properly?

Comment: this one works great var x = db.Doors.Where(d => d.CarId == car.CarId).Min(d => d.Weight);

Comment: @YegorRazumovsky And what SQL is that translated into?

Comment: @YegorRazumovsky Also, make sure that `Weight` is an indexed column.  It could just be that finding the minimum weight is an expensive operation because of the amount of data that you have, if it's not index.  Obviously filtering on ID is going to be much quicker, even if everything is working properly; that's not an appropriate comparison.  The question is whether it's translated into SQL properly in each case.

Comment: Weight column has index